# g++ vs intel/clang argument passing order?

Tags: c++, c++11, arguments, standards-compliance, c++-chrono

Consider the following code ([LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/JOaST%247)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

inline void test(
   const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point& first, 
   const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point& second)
{
   std::cout << first.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
   std::cout << second.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   test(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(), 
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
   return 0;
}
```

You have to run it several times because sometimes, there is no visible difference. But when there is a visible difference between the time of evaluation of `first` and `second`, the result is the following under g++ :

```
1363376239363175
1363376239363174
```

and the following under intel and clang :

```
1363376267971435
1363376267971436
```

It means that under g++, the `second` argument is evaluated first, and under intel and clang the `first` argument is evaluated first.

Which one is true according to the C++11 standard?

Comment: Neat way of finding the evaluation order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Which one is true according to the C++11 standard ?

Both are permissible. To quote the standard (§8.3.6):

> The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspeciﬁed.

Comment: Yup. This has bitten me a few times in my career, in fact. The ambiguity of evaluation of function arguments can lead to EXTREMELY subtle problems. (I remember one time where this bug existed for years, and I couldn't find the root cause, and the only workaround I could find was TURNING OFF OPTIMIZATION FOR THAT CPP. Ouch.)

Comment: Also, the order might depend on the optimization flags used and on the rest of the code.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Yeah, and even if you are aware of undefined argument evaluation order, you have to keep in mind that the object a method is called on is just another argument, too. Happened to me one time because I thought *"well, to call a method through `->`, it has to first evaluate the left hand side before even starting to look at the method arguments, doesn't it?"*.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly simpler example to illustrate the same problem.

```
bash$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 0;
int foo() 
{
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    return x++;
}
int bar()
{
    cout << "bar" << endl;
    return x++;
}
void test_it(int a, int b)
{
    cout << "a = " << a << endl
        << "b = " << b << endl;

}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    test_it(foo(),bar()); 
    return 0;
}

bash$ clang++ test.cpp && ./a.out
foo
bar
a = 0
b = 1
bash$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.out
bar
foo
a = 1
b = 0
```